# Select attribute in simplexml

Tags: simplexml

The xml data looks like this:

```
<feed>    
    <entry>
      <id>12345</id>
      <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
      <link type="type1" href="https://foo.bar" />
      <link type="type2" href="https://foo2.bar"/>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <id>56789</id>
      <title>ipsum</title>
      <link type="type2" href="https://foo4.bar"/>
      <link type="type1" href="https://foo3.bar" />
    </entry>
</feed>
```

I want to select the content of the href attribute from a link with certain type. (note that type 1 is not always the first link)

Part of the code that works:

```
for($i=0; $i<=5; $i++) {
    foreach($xml->entry[$i]->link as $a) {
        if($a["type"] == "type2")
            $link = (string)($a["href"]);
    }
}
```

However, I wonder if there is a faster and more elegant solution to this that does not require a foreach loop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using xpath? http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

This will allow you to do a search for nodes with the specified tag/attribute.

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//link[@type="type2"]');
foreach ($node in $nodes)
{
    $link = $node['href'];
}
```

**// Updated**

You can skip the for loop if you are interested in only the first value.  The `xpath` function returns an array of `SimpleXmlElement` objects so you can use index `0` to retrieve the first element, and then it's property.

Note - If the element is missing or cannot be found, the `xpath` element will return `false`, and the below code will error.  The code is for illustration only, so you should verify error checking when implementing it.

```
// This will work if the xml always has the required attrbiute - will error if it's missing
$link = $xml->xpath('//link['@type="type2"]')[0]['href'];
```

Comment: It seems I can omit the if statement this way, but is there anything like
    $link = $xml->xpath('//link[@type="type2"]->href')
to directly select an attribute depending on another attribute?

Can't find that in the manual, but perhaps I just don't see it.

Comment: $link = $xml->xpath('//link['@type="type2"]')[0]['href'];

Answer (score 0):

Use [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php):

```
$xml->xpath('//link[@type="type2"]');
```

More on the language [at w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)